# How to load large image form DataBase as byte[] in ASP.Net MVC to use in any ajax jquery image popUp

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, html, lightbox

Developers. I'm new in APS.Net and MVC 4 ofcourse.

I try to create usual gallery, when user click on small image - ajax load bigger one and show it in popUp.. or lightBox if you like.

**Problem is** data system, images stored into database (SQL Server) as byte[].
I can load smaller img in View like that:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, @System.Convert.ToBase64String(item.PictureLQ) " alt=" " />
```

**item.PictureHQ** - large image, i need to load and show it only by ckicking on the smaler one.

How can i use my byte array for load image in lightbox only after click?

P.S.: Its better to do it with simple jquery+ajax and without any overloaded functionality just popUp, show description and img, close.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a file downloader. A controller with an action that grabs the bytes from the DB and converts them to a file stream with the correct content type would work, if you are in MVC. Then your src would be something like:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Download","Downloader", new{id=123})" />
```

Comment: looks usefull, can you please give me some explanation about using controllers like that? "Download" action need to return View with byte array as model. Then how View looks like to implement the src?
And how ajax works with this solution?